# Attach to process with gdbserver without stop it

Tags: gdb

I run gdbserver
`gdbserver --attach :<port> <pid>` and then connect with gdb-multiarch

The problem is that until I connect with gdb-multiarch and run `c` the process is stop.

Can I continue the process after I attach with `gdbserver` inside hte machine that run gdbserver ?

Answer (score 3):

The main built-in way I see to do this is to use `gdbserver --multi` without attaching to a process at that time. Then, you connect with `target extended-remote` in gdb, and then run the `attach <pid>` in gdb.

You could also instead use a wrapper on the debugee to not start `gdbserver` until a connection is made:

```
$ socat tcp-l:<port>,reuseaddr,fork exec:"gdbserver --once --attach <pid>"
```

Statically compiled builds of `socat` can be made by you or often found online.

Comment: , I looking for a way into server machine ,not into client machine. I just don't want that process will wait until `gdb-multiarch` will connet

Comment: Ok, edited and gave two options.